# selecting "friends" with mySQL JOIN CASE 

Tags: mysql, join, case

Here i posted a question about doing JOIN depending on the value of the column in the row.
You will need that is you make an Add Friend feature, where you write the ID of the 2 users who are Adding each other into `user_1_id` (my id) and  `user_2_id` (friend id). 
When you want to see who you are friends with, select DEPENDING on whether `user_1_id` or `user_2_id` has the ID of the surrent User (the one who is browsing)

I figured it out so down below is the query you want to use in case you need to do it.

Here is the query

```
$sql_inp = 'SELECT DISTINCT
                 users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name,
    CASE 
                 WHEN friends.user_2_id="'.$_SESSION[USER][id].'" //equal to current user id
                 THEN (SELECT friends.user_1_id FROM friends WHERE friends.user_2_id="'.$_SESSION[USER][id].'") // if user_2_id is My id, then fetch the other row
         ELSE friends.user_2_id // obviously the opposite
    END  
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN friends ON users.id=    // this case is completely the same as one above
    CASE 
                 WHEN friends.user_2_id="'.$_SESSION[USER][id].'" THEN (SELECT friends.user_1_id FROM friends WHERE friends.user_2_id="'.$_SESSION[USER][id].'") 
    ELSE friends.user_2_id 
        END 
    WHERE  friends.user_1_id="'.$_SESSION[USER][id].'" OR  friends.user_2_id="'.$_SESSION[USER][id].'" // fetch the row where the either one of the values is equal to My id 
  ';
```

Hope this helps if anyone had trouble

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you're after. Can you post your schema along with some sample data and some expected results?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I hate using CASE statement. It makes queries look cluttered. Try using the [IF function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
$sql_inp = 'SELECT
    table1.val1,table1.val2,
            table2.val1,table2.val2,
            IF(table3.val1="'.$user_id.'",table3.val1,
            IF(table3.val2 ="'.$user_id.'",table3.val2,
            IFNULL(table3.val2,-1))) users_fetch
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.val1=table1.val1
    LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.val1=users_fetch';
```

In this query, if table3.val1 and table3.val2 <> $user_id, then users_fetch is -1.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: i tried doing what you did, and your code makes perfect sence. even with cases it shoudl work, but i keep on getting error message